# Storing Url into Firebase -Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am able to store my images into my database. In my image table, i want the url itself but when i save the image i get this kind of url(i can't tell if it is a url or not) which looks like `"md59ff87d3098d3e76b10bcffd04c4d249f.Image@429ed2f8"` but i want something like `firebase.com/pet.jpg` so i can call it back into my imageview. The problem seems to be in my `OnSuccess()`. How do i get this done please?

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == Result.Ok && data != null && data.Data != null)
            {

                uri = data.Data;

                try
                {

                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(ContentResolver, uri);
                    imageViewDrop.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);

                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                {

                    e.StackTrace.ToString();
                }

                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.StackTrace.ToString();
                }

                if (uri != null)
                {
                    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
                    pd.SetTitle("Uploading Profile Picture");
                    pd.Show();

                    StorageReference image = storageRef.Child(FB_STORAGE_PATH +System.DateTime.Today + "." + GetImageExt(uri));


                    image.PutFile(uri).AddOnSuccessListener(this).AddOnFailureListener(this);

                    image.PutFile(uri).AddOnProgressListener(this);




               }

            }
        }

        public string GetImageExt(Android.Net.Uri uri)
        {

            ContentResolver contentresolver = ContentResolver;
            MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.Singleton;
            return mime.GetExtensionFromMimeType(contentresolver.GetType(uri));


        }

        public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
        {
            pd.Dismiss();

            Toast.MakeText(this, "Image Uploaded Successfully", ToastLength.Short).Show();

            ImageUpload uploads = new ImageUpload(uri.ToString());

            string uploadId = mDatabaseImage.Push().Key;
            mDatabaseImage.Child(user.Uid).Child(phId).Child(uploadId).SetValue(uploads.ToString());



        }
```

**update**

```
  protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);



            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == Result.Ok && data != null && data.Data != null)
            {
                uri = data.Data;

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

                    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
                    pd.SetTitle("Uploading Profile Picture");
                    pd.Show();
                    StorageReference oneRef = storageRef.Child("one " + i + "png.");
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(ContentResolver, uri);
                    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                    bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
                    byte[] myData = stream.ToArray();

                    uploadTask = oneRef.PutBytes(myData);
                    uploadTask.AddOnSuccessListener(this);
                    uploadTask.AddOnFailureListener(this);
                }
        }

        public string GetImageExt(Android.Net.Uri uri)
        {

            ContentResolver contentresolver = ContentResolver;
            MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.Singleton;
            return mime.GetExtensionFromMimeType(contentresolver.GetType(uri));


        }

        public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
        {
             pd.Dismiss();
            string uploadId = mDatabaseImage.Push().Key;
            var snapshot = result as SnapshotBase;
            var url = snapshot.Storage.Path;
            mDatabaseImage.Child(count.ToString()).Child(user.Uid).Child(phId).Child(uploadId).SetValue(new PeaceHeroImage(url).ToMap());

            Toast.MakeText(this, "Image Uploaded Successfully", ToastLength.Short).Show();





        }

        public void OnFailure(Java.Lang.Exception e)
        {
            pd.Dismiss();

            Toast.MakeText(this, e.Message, ToastLength.Short).Show();

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast your result to UploadTask so as to get the DownloadUrl like this

```
public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
        {
             pd.Dismiss();
            string uploadId = mDatabaseImage.Push().Key;
            var snapshot = result as SnapshotBase;
            string url = ((UploadTask.TaskSnapshot)result).DownloadUrl.ToString();
            mDatabaseImage.Child(count.ToString()).Child(user.Uid).Child(phId).Child(uploadId).SetValue(new PeaceHeroImage(url).ToMap());

            Toast.MakeText(this, "Image Uploaded Successfully", ToastLength.Short).Show();

        }
```

Comment: Thank you..This is what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

> but i want something like firebase.com/pet.jpg so i can call it back into my imageview.

From your code I think you're uploading your images to `Firebase Storage` and then you can save the path of this image to your `Firebase Database` for example like this:

```
public class MyActivity : Activity, IOnSuccessListener, IOnFailureListener, IValueEventListener
{
    private DatabaseReference dbRef;
    private StorageReference imagesRef;
    private int count;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout2);

        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.Instance;
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.CurrentUser;
        if (user == null)
        {
            var result = mAuth.SignInAnonymously();
        }

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.Instance;
        dbRef = database.GetReference("mygallery");

        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.Instance;
        //create child reference
        StorageReference storageRef = storage.Reference;
        imagesRef = storageRef.Child("images");

        Button btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.createdb);
        btn.Click += Btn_Click;
    }

    private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //upload to firebase storage
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            StorageReference oneRef = imagesRef.Child("one" + i + ".png");
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(this.Resources, Resource.Drawable.one);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
            byte[] data = stream.ToArray();

            UploadTask uploadtask = oneRef.PutBytes(data);
            uploadtask.AddOnSuccessListener(this);
            uploadtask.AddOnFailureListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void OnFailure(Java.Lang.Exception e)
    {
        Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Debug, "storage", "Failed:" + e.ToString());
        Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Failed", ToastLength.Short);
    }

    public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
        Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Debug, "storage", "success!");
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Success", ToastLength.Short);

        //retrieve url and name of uploaded image and insert to database
        var snapshot = result as SnapshotBase;
        var name = snapshot.Storage.Name;
        var uri = snapshot.Storage.Path;
        dbRef.Child(count.ToString()).Child("name").SetValue(name);
        dbRef.Child(count.ToString()).Child("imageurl").SetValue(uri);
        count++;
    }

    public void OnCancelled(DatabaseError error)
    {
        Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Debug, "database", "Cancelled:" + error.ToString());
        Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Failed", ToastLength.Short);
    }

    public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Success", ToastLength.Short);
    }
}
```

Here is the screen shot of my firebase storage and database:

[image: Storage]

[image: Database]

Comment: i need the download url itself not the path..The download url inorder to make a request for it into an imageview

Comment: And also with your code, when i upload a pic for one blog it appears fine, but then when i upload another image for another blog, it replaces the first image in the storage. so instead of having two photos in my storage, i have just 1

Comment: @Amateur, please make sure every time you update a blog, use a different name for it, in my code `StorageReference oneRef = imagesRef.Child("one" + i + ".png");` is for different files, with different ref,  the old one then will not be replaced. And I understand that the uri is used for downloading, but firebase storage downloading is not based on the download url (it is manually changeable and not exposed to us), the path we get can be analyzed to create a download task.

Comment: Grace, Please look at my update. When i upload a single pic, it appears 5 times in my storage and in my database.

Comment: @Amateur, ...emmmmmmmmmm, I used one single source to upload with five names so to simulator the scenario for uploading several files.............It's a demo supposed to help you understand where to get the path, please don't use `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` for one single source...

Comment: Okay .. i got that working but the storage path can't get me the image back. When i hard code, the download url into my database inplace of the storage path, i am able to get the image in my imageView

Comment: I don't know if am making myself clearer. In my database, i do not want the storage path.. I want this `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/app/o/image%2F04%2F07%2F2017%2000%3A00%3A00.jpeg?alt=medi` so i can just use mappings to fectch the url as in my question. But in your code, you save the storage path instead into your database

Comment: That is what i was asked to use basically. I don't really understand how the storage path works from your comment. I have to save the http download file and make a request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148480/discussion-between-amateur-and-grace-feng-msft).

Comment: My question was not using storage path :) . I am basically looking for storing the url as the download url like in the question..  then i make a request

Comment: I get it but that is my assignment. i am suppose to use http request not google's api :)